# Android status bar icon design

Tags: android, icons, statusbar

I'm working on a little app, and one of things that has been bugging me is the design of a status bar icon that looks good on all phones

The problem is that if you follow the official design guidelines ([http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#statusbarstructure)) you get an icon which looks great on phones running "standard Android" (2.2 and lower), which have light grey status bars, but phones running a customised UI (or Android 2.3) generally have black or dark grey status bars, and the beautifully designed icon you've just created looks rather out of place and amateurish on such a phone

Does anyone have any good suggestions for design of such icons?

Comment: I bet you if you wait a little bit there will be new guidelines out about the icons for 2.3.

Answer (score 2):

Many apps have an option in the "preferences" section that allows users to swap the icon from a "light" color to a "dark" color allowing support for multiple notification bar colors.

Comment: yup im working on one which detects the phones make/model and android version and then chooses either a black or light grey icon automatically